# GLIBC_2.17 have been installed but still got "`GLIBC_2.14' not found " error

Tags: linux, server, rcpp

I am a green hand about linux and I am using a server to run my R code through qsub xx.pbs. When I library "Rcpp" package, I got this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcpp’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/data/user77/Rlib/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /data/user77/Rlib/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so)
```

However, when I used `ldd --version` to find out what is the current version of `glibc`, I got this:

```
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
```

When I ran `/lib64/libc.so.6`, I got this:

```
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.17, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23).
Compiled on a Linux 2.6.32 system on 2021-01-02.
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot for your providing solutions!

**(PS: I am not allowed to use sudo.)**

Comment: Talk to your sysadmin. Your build below `/data/user77/` is out of sync with the libraries; the usual fix is a rebuild. That is entirely at your end.

Comment: To Dirk Eddelbuettel: Thank you! But would you please explain more about what exactly my sysadmin and I need to do? I am really sorry that I just got to learn about linux.

Comment: Your sysadmin will know / should know.  The _compiled_ version of Rcpp you are trying to use is out of sync with the _installed_ version of libc6 as you found.  That can happen if one changes the latter without recompiling the former, copies in from another system (in general you cannot do that) and alike.  As you may be a new user of that system, I would recommend to rely on the available local help. In the mean time, one working (and free, to a limit) system _with Rcpp_ is provided by https://rstudio.cloud.